# ngIf on input value

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-directive

I have field which get the input of the user and according to it the below element will show what has been written

```
 <label>message</label>
 <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="person.message"class="form-control">

 <label class="label">you've written this </label>
 <input type="text" name="name" disabled value="{{message}}" class="form-control">
```

**this code works fine** but I want to assign a condition to the shown value which is somthing like this:
`*ngIf=person.message!=null?{{message}}":'write'`

which means if the input filed is not null show what is written else show the word write

Comment: What is the purpose of the word "write"? Shouldn't you use a `placeholder` instead (e.g. `placeholder="write"`)?

Comment: @ConnorsFan it is a point of vue but I wanted to learn how to put a condition on an input value, it may serves me on another case :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) within [`{{...}}`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation-and-template-expressions)

```
 <input type="text" name="name" disabled value="{{person.message!=null ? message : 'write'}}" class="form-control">
```

Or set value as a property with [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
<input type="text" name="name" disabled [value]="person.message!=null ? message : 'write'" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the value exist or not else assign the default valus usng OR operator.

```
<label>message</label>
     <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="person.message" class="form-control">

     <label class="label">you've written this </label>
     <input type="text" name="name" disabled [value]="person.message ? message : 'write'" class="form-control">
```

Comment: this code just verify if `person.message` exists it does not show the message

Comment: Can you please tell how and where are you setting message from person.message? Are they always in sync?

Comment: I'm getting message from `[(ngModel)]` in **ts** and then I'm showing it in the html !

Comment: I have updated my answer with base logic as I am not sure how message and person.message are linked so removed old logic.